# How to *not* change the file extension while changing a filename?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, extension-methods

I'm trying to remove the numbers from the file name. But in doing so it also removes the extension and the `mp4` file turns into a `mp`. What is a good solution to solve this?

```
import os

def file_rename():
    name_list=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Twitch")
    print(name_list)
    saved_path=os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is"+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Twitch")

    for file_name in name_list:
        print("old name"+file_name)
        print("new name"+file_name.strip("0123456789"))
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans('','','0123456789-')))
    os.chdir(saved_path)

file_rename()
```

Comment: if the file name as an extension (`my_file.ext`) make sure you only clean the part before the dot.

Comment: You can cut the name at the ".", so you have two strings and only remove the numbers in the first one. Then put it back together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pathlib.Path objects. It has [`name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) and [`suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) attributes, and a [rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) method:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
for file in Path(r'C:\tmp').glob('*'):
    if not file.is_file():
        continue
    new_name = re.sub('\d','', file.stem) + file.suffix
    file.rename(file.parent/new_name)
```

The [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) attribute gives the folder the file belongs to and the [`is_file`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) method is used to check that we are handing a regular file (and not a folder). New Path objects are created easily with the `/` operator (full new filepath is  `file.parent / new_name`).

The `re.sub()` is used to replace the numbers (`\d` means a digit) in the old filename `stem` part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re`, e.g.

```
import re, os, glob

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(yourdir,'*')):    
    old_name=os.path.basename(f)
    old_split = old_name.split('.')
    ext = old_split[-1]
    new_name=re.sub('\d','',''.join(old_split[:-1])) + '.' + ext
    new_f=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f),new_name)
    os.rename(f, new_f)
```

Here you first extract the base name, then it split to get the extension. Next you build the new base name by replacing all the numbers in the old basename with an empty string and add the extension.

You then build the full path and rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
remove = set("0123456789-")
fname = 'my_file1-new12.mp4'
parts = fname.split('.')
parts[0] = ''.join(x for x in parts[0] if x not in remove)
clean_fname = parts[0] + '.' + parts[1]
print(clean_fname)
```

output

```
my_filenew.mp4
```

Comment: Do not ever assume that there is only one dot in your filename. It will bite you in the arse eventually.

Answer (score -1):

This Simple Regex will solve your problem in your for loop. It will first take the filenames before first single dot , will group it..Then you can strip all the required numbers from filename for renaming purpose .

```
    find = re.compile(r"^[^.]*")
    for file_name in name_list:
        print (re.search(find, file_name).group(0))
        new_name = re.search(find, file_name).group(0)
        print("new name are"+ new_name.strip("0123456789"))
```